# SQL Server Compact filtered indexes

Tags: sql-server-ce, filtered-index

Are filtered indexes supported in any version of SQL Server Compact?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and installed [Books Online for SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21880) and found no traces of filtered indexes, and the syntax diagram doesn't include a where clause:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] [NONCLUSTERED] INDEX index_name 
ON table_name (column_name [ASC|DESC][,…n])
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = { ON | OFF })]
```

So I believe the answer is, no, SQL Server Compact does not support filtered indexes. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Silly me, Books Online is about the only place I didn't check :P